# Library to classify text on affect

Tags: nlp, classification

Are there libraries out there for the automatic classification of text in for example English on affect? If it's quite rough it might still be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, when I see the term "affect classification" used, its describing processing of voice data, not text-- using audio features such as spectrum, loudness, etc to determine if a speaker is angry, frustrated, etc. These types of features obviously don't translate well to text.

When speaking of classifying text, its more common to refer to classifying [Sentiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis), aka "Opinion Mining" to determine if the author of a text is speaking positively or negatively about the text's subject. If this provides enough nuance for you needs, fortunately there are a large amount of resources to help you with this. In Python, the Natural Language Toolkit provides classifiers that are often used for this type of work, for example [this demo](http://text-processing.com/demo/).

The downside of this approach, is that it generally is limited to positive/negative classification, and that it is very domain specific. For example, a classifier trained to detect positive movie reviews will perform poorly at classifying software reviews.

There is also some work that has been done on emotion classification in text, for example this [paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=feeler%20text%20vector%20classification&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.189.3795%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=ev2mTqvEM7PJ0AHdney_Dg&usg=AFQjCNGZNXgKeDDLEPNxjV7RLbWSA1mnAA&cad=rja) as well as [this one on identifying the emotional content of blog posts](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.111.2693&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  Unfortunately it appears this you are less likely to find as much 'pre canned' library support for this task, but given the information in the research, you should be able to build this type of a system on top of something like [NLTK](http://nltk.org) or other classification / natural language processing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The "Pattern" system is used for sentiment analysis:

- Belgian elections, June 13, 2010 - Twitter opinion mining http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-examples-elections
- Pattern, http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern
- MBSP, a text analysis system for Python, http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/MBSP